# configure defender with configfile

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to Configure the Windows Defender using Powershell.
Therefore i have a file (.txt) with the desired configuratin in it.

> ScanScheduleDay = 7
>
> DisableCatchupFullScan = True
>
> DisableRealtimeMonitoring = False

This script will run every X hours using Taskscheduler.
It shall then scan the current configuration and check if it is different than the desired configuration in the .txt file. If there is a change i want to do sepcific things so i need to be able to know what changed.

I cant figure out, how to seperate the Confiuration name and the value from my .txt file.

```
if (!($config -eq $value))
{
Set-MpPreference -$config $value
}
```

so $config should be the first thing in the .txt (for example ScanScheduleDay) and $value should be the value after the " = " (for example 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of doing that is to read the config text file and convert it into a hashtable. Then compare what the current setting is to what is desired:

```
# read the desired config text file and convert to Hashtable
$txt = Get-Content -Path 'D:\DefenderConfig.txt' -Raw | ConvertFrom-StringData

# get the current configuration
$currentConfig = Get-MpPreference

# loop through the settings from the text file and report the differences
$txt.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    $currentValue = $currentConfig.$($_.Name)
    if ($_.Value -ne $currentValue) {
        # there is a difference found. 
        # for demo, just show on screen
        Write-Host "Current value for '$($_.Name)': $currentValue - Desired: $($_.Value)"
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Current value for 'DisableCatchupFullScan': False - Desired: True
Current value for 'ScanScheduleDay': 0 - Desired: 7
```

Comment: with that my desired configuration in the $txt have to be the same format as the output of Get-MpPreference?

Comment: @Dragonball2211 Yes, it would be awkward if you use other setting names that are applicable to the `Get-MpPreference` or `Set-MpPreference` cmdlets. It _can_ be done, but then you would need a second Hashtable object where the self-defined setting aliases can be matched to the _real_ setting names.

Answer (score 0):

Now that i have that sorted i try to reset any settings that dont match my .txt file.

I have the Name of the Setting (ScanScheduleDay as an example) in a variable `$conname`

Also the desired value is in `$currentValue`

i get the error:

`Set-MpPreference : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-ScanScheduleDay'.
At C:\temp\defendertest\Defendersettings.ps1:120 char:1
+ Set-MpPreference "-$conname" $currentValue
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-MpPreference], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Set-MpPreference`

Cant i just use a variable as the parameter?